# Существительные, заканчивающиеся на "-ние" и -"нье".

Tags: орфография

Есть много существительных, заканчивающихся на "-ние" или "-нье" (спасе**ние**, гуля**нье** и др.). Есть ли какие правила, регулирующие, когда пишется через "и", а когда через "ь", и насколько нормативны вариации одного и того же слова, записанные по разному?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не могу согласиться, что это варианты равнозначные. Бывает, и так. Но не всегда. Во-первых, в некоторых словах все-таки есть смысловое различие. Например, варение - варенье. Если слово имеет значение процесса, действия, то *варение* правильно, и *варенье*, как разговорный вариант, тоже. Если значение  результата действия (сладкое варенье), то правильным будет только *варенье*. То же со словами печенье, соленье.  Во- вторых, есть слова, которые просто  варианта не имеют. Например, слово "правописание".  Варианта с мягким знаком  даже представить не могу.  (Наверное, потому, что это слово никак не обиходное, не бытовое, да и значения  результата действия у него нет. Только значение процесса). Так что, понимая общие смысловые и стилистические различия, при сомнении лучше обратиться к словарю.

Answer (score 2):

Строгих правил по этому вопросу нет. Обе формы являются равнозначными, при этом -ие предпочтительнее в книжной речи, а -ье - в разговорном стиле

Comment: Да, в разговоре чаще краткая форма употребляется (на -*нье*) : лазанье, старанье, стремленье. А также в поэзии, где необходимо соблюсти размер : "Сомненья прочь, уходит в ночь отдельный..." Там  мы находим желанье, сопоставленье, боренье,  "мгновенье, виденье, заточенье, упоенье,  пробужденье,  вдохновенье, и жизнь, и слезы, и любовь". И даже *правописанье* найдем в детских стихах!

Answer (score 1):

В целом, [[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f) ответила правильно, но думаю тут не лишним будет дать и выдержку из "Справочника по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию" [Розенталя](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/28.htm#_top) (§37 п. 7).

> Написание -ние (-ание, -ение) или -нье (-анье, -енье) в суффиксах отглагольных существительных связано или со смысловым различием, или со стилистической дифференциацией.
> 1)      В смысловом отношении различаются: *варение, печение, соление* [процесс, то же, что «варка», «выпечка», «засол» – *варенье, печенье, соленье* (результат процесса, продукт); *воскресение* (действие по глаголу воскресить) – *воскресенье* (день недели); *жалование* (пожалование, присуждение) — *жалованье* (денежное вознаграждение за работу)] и т.п.
>
> 2)      Слова книжные пишутся с суффиксом -ние, слова обиходные — с суффиксом -нье, например:
> а)      *воспитание, достижение, замедление, искоренение, оформление, процветание, разграничение, склонение, усыновление, формирование, членение, явление;
>
> б)      барахтанье, беганье, воркованье, дерганье, кваканье, кряхтенье, тявканье, фырканье, харканье, хихиканье, чавканье, чириканье, шиканье, щелканье.*